# How to prevent script from being stopped

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script running in a window.
The window is necessary since it gives to the user the information what exactly is running. The script waits simply for IE to terminate.

```
while ( $ieProc.Responding) {
$Message = "Running " + $script + ":" + $script[$nr] + " please do not close this window !!!"
write $Message
sleep 5
}
```

It is written, please do not close this window, but some users do !!!
Since after this while loop the script has to do some cleanup work, I am not very happy if users can interrupt the script.
How do I make sure that the cleanup is performed by the script even if the user closes the window?

Comment: interrupt-handling is definitely not what you think it is

Comment: You could try and run the script minimized, but users still may wreck havoc. What you really need is to do is to understand the users' motivation. *Why* are they closing the window? After you've figured out the motivation, solutions are easier to find out.

Comment: Take a look at Function Input Processing Methods (Begin..Process..End) Link:https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-function-input.html You can do your clean up part in the end section

Comment: See my answer. You will have to modify it to suits your need but if you hide your script window and start a second script which purposes is to display the content output of your first script, that would do it. User closing the window would not affect the script doing the work, only the display of informations.

Answer (score 1):

You could actually decompose your script into 2. 
One would do the actual work and one would do the display.

Therefore, if the user close the display window, the actual script would remain open.

For instance, take:

- ScriptThatWorkHard.ps1
- ScriptThatDisplayThings.ps1

**ScriptThatWorkHard.ps1** launch using `-WindowStyleHidden` so it pop out of existence right away.

The user won't be able to close that window.

That script, immediately launch **ScriptThatDisplayThings.ps1**

In order for them to communicate (you want the first script to send the content to display to the second script), I would pipe all the content produced by the hidden script into a file that the second script will monitor.

By monitoring LastWriteTime, the second script can detect changes made to the file and display its content.

Somewhat simplistic but here's what the second script could look like : 
(Except in your real script, instead of a "datelimit" to exit the script, you should user some other methodology)

```
if (Test-Path $logFullPath) {
$LastModifiedTime = (Get-ChildItem -Path $logFullPath).LastWriteTime
$DateLimit = (Get-Date).AddSeconds(10)

       While ((Get-date) -le $DateLimit) {
       $NewLastModifiedDate = (Get-ChildItem -Path $logFullPath).LastWriteTime
       if ($LastModifiedTime -ne $NewLastModifiedDate) {
            $LastModifiedTime = $NewLastModifiedDate
            $DateLimit = (Get-Date).AddSeconds(10)
            Write-Host 'The unread lines from your logfile'
       }
    }
}
```

This is by no way a complete example but a start.

For instance, you could detect and use a special line in your log to pass commands to your display script (such as **shutdown** so it knows when to close instead of a "datelimit")

Also, you would have to implement the "reading the log file new content" part.

The result of using that methodology however, is quite clear.
If the annoyed user close the window, he is actually closing the information window, not the running script underneath.

Comment: it should be also possible to reopen closed display window in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider to completely hide your PowerShell Window as follows:

```
$Win32 = Add-Type -MemberDefinition '
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
' -Name "Win32Functions" -NameSpace Win32Functions -PassThru 
[Void]($Win32::ShowWindowAsync((Get-Process -id $pid).MainWindowHandle, 0))
```

The only way to terminate the script is through the task manager which is unlikely done by the user.