# Script that prompts users to restart PC with option to delay, then forces a restart after the delay

Tags: powershell, delay, prompt, restart

I have the following script that is successful in prompting users to restart their computers. The script prompts users to restart their computers every 10 minutes for an hour. Users can delay the restart each time. However, the script doesn't force the restart once the 60 minutes has expired. Also, the PS session window is open throughout the 60 minutes that the script is running - is there a way to hide the PS window from view? Thank you for your help!

I've added code that I'd hoped would display a notification and proceed with a forced restart, but am receiving the following error in PS:

> "Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date'. Cannot convert value "if" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "The string was
> not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0."
> At C:\scripts\Reboot_Toast.ps1:47 char:21
>
> - $TimeNow = Get-Date if ($TimeNow -ge $TimeEnd) { shutdown -r -f -t 60 ...

The entire script is as follows:

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | out-null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") | out-null
$TimeStart = Get-Date
$TimeEnd = $timeStart.addminutes(60)
Do
{
    $TimeNow = Get-Date
    if ($TimeNow -ge $TimeEnd)
    {
        
        Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier click_event -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        Remove-Event click_event -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
        [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
        Exit
    }
    else
    {
        $Balloon = new-object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
        $Balloon.Icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::Information
        $Balloon.BalloonTipText = "IT is requiring a reboot in order to maintain system stability supporting IT security measures. Please reboot at your earliest convenience."
        $Balloon.BalloonTipTitle = "Reboot Required"
        $Balloon.BalloonTipIcon = "Warning"
        $Balloon.Visible = $true;
        $Balloon.ShowBalloonTip(20000);
        $Balloon_MouseOver = [System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler]{ $Balloon.ShowBalloonTip(20000) }
        $Balloon.add_MouseClick($Balloon_MouseOver)
        Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier click_event -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        Register-ObjectEvent $Balloon BalloonTipClicked -sourceIdentifier click_event -Action {
            Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
            
            If ([Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::MsgBox('Would you like to reboot your machine now?', 'YesNo,MsgBoxSetForeground,Question', 'System Maintenance') -eq "NO")
            { }
            else
            {
                shutdown -r -f
            }
            
        } | Out-Null
        
        Wait-Event -timeout 600 -sourceIdentifier click_event > $null
        Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier click_event -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $Balloon.Dispose()

$TimeNow = Get-Date if ($TimeNow -ge $TimeEnd) { shutdown -r -f -t 600 -c "You have reached the allotted time for reboot delay. Please save your work and reboot or your computer will automatically reboot in 10 minutes." }

    }

}
Until ($TimeNow -ge $TimeEnd)
```

Comment: To hide the PowerShell window feom within the session itself, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46586143/1701026

Answer (score 0):

This should be two lines, not one:

```
$TimeNow = Get-Date if ($TimeNow -ge $TimeEnd) { shutdown -r -f -t 600 -c "You have reached the allotted time for reboot delay. Please save your work and reboot or your computer will automatically reboot in 10 minutes."
```

Put a line break after `Get-Date` i.e.

```
$TimeStart = Get-Date
$TimeEnd = $TimeStart.addseconds(10)
Write-Host "Waiting" -NoNewline
Do {
    $TimeNow = Get-Date
    Write-Host "." -NoNewline
    If ($TimeNow -ge $TimeEnd) {
        Write-Host "Time's up"
    # shutdown -r -f -t 600 -c "You have reached the allotted time for reboot delay. Please save your work and reboot or your computer will automatically reboot in 10 minutes."
    }
    Sleep 1
}
Until ($TimeNow -ge $TimeEnd)
```

If you launch your script as follows, it should hide the PS console window:

```
powershell.exe -Windowstyle Hidden -File PathToScript.ps1
```